# Split ConfigMap in two with using Kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, kustomize

I have the following `ConfigMap`. I'm trying to split the two datasources out into two separate files, and merge them at "build time" using Kustomize.

But I just can't figure out how to do that?

This is what I have:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: grafana-datasources
  namespace: grafana
data:
  datasources.yaml: |-
    apiVersion: 1
    datasources:
      - name: prometheus
        type: prometheus
        access: proxy
        url: http://prometheus:9090
        isDefault: true
        version: 1
      - name: Azure Monitor
        type: grafana-azure-monitor-datasource
        access: proxy
        version: 1
```

The parts I want to split into separate files (and later merge into a ConfigMap) are:

```
      - name: prometheus
        type: prometheus
        access: proxy
        url: http://prometheus:9090
        isDefault: true
        version: 1
```

And:

```
      - name: Azure Monitor
        type: grafana-azure-monitor-datasource
        access: proxy
        version: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create two separate files for datasource.
Create directory to put the base configuration:

```
$ mkdir -p $DEMO_HOME/base
```

First datasource should look like this:

```
$ cat <<EOF >$DEMO_HOME/base/datasource1.yaml
```

```
  apiVersion: 1
    datasources:
      - name: prometheus
        type: prometheus
        access: proxy
        url: http://prometheus:9090
        isDefault: true
        version: 1
```

Second datasource should look like this:

```
$ cat <<EOF >$DEMO_HOME/base/datasource2.yaml
```

```
  apiVersion: 1
    datasources:
      - name: Azure Monitor
        type: grafana-azure-monitor-datasource
        access: proxy
        version: 1
```

```
    $ cat <<EOF >$DEMO_HOME/base/kustomization.yaml
```

Then in kustomization file pass info about configmap and add files:

```
$ cat <<EOF >$DEMO_HOME/base/kustomization.yaml
```

```
configMapGenerator:
- name: my-configmap
  files:
  - datasource1.yaml
  - datasource2.yaml
EOF
```

Finally you can generate the configMaps for development:

```
$ kustomize build $DEMO_HOME/base
```

Please take a look: [kustomize-operation](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/combineConfigs.md#create-and-use-the-overlay-for-development), [kustomize](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/897).

**EDIT:**

You can also split ConfigMap into two separate ConfigMaps which both of them will include one file.
First one with `datasources1.yaml` and second one with `datasources2.yaml`.

Comment: I think OP is looking for a final ConfigMap that contains a single key `datasources.yml` with everything merge in it.

Comment: @ITChap Yes, you are right. Fortunately I figured out that "datasources.yaml" isn't a required name for the file in the ConfigMap. So I can have two ConfigMaps with separate files names for example "datasources_1.yaml" and "datasources_2.yaml"

Comment: Yes, you are right, splitting it into two configmap it is also good idea, however I think my solution is also proper. I have updated my answer with workaround with two separate configmaps also.

Comment: Can the file format for data be json ?